# Запуск файла на хостинге

Tags: python, хостинг

На хостинге есть файл, написанный на питоне try.py. Как можно запустить его через консоль, чтобы можно было её закрыть, его выполнение продолжалось, а потом можно было подключиться к его выполнению (к примеру файл каждую минуту выводит текст на экран, а мне необходимо его увидеть)?

Comment: Использовать screen или tmux или запустить его через systemd или supervisor (при условии что хостинг не будет вырубать фоновые процессы)

Comment: @andreymal, а также старый добрый `nohup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## systemd

Для запуска на systemd создайте файл /etc/systemd/system/try.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Try Server

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /opt/try/try.py
WorkingDirectory=/opt/try/


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Старт

```
systemctl start try.service
```

Автозапуск

```
systemctl enable try.service
```

Посмотреть журнал (вывод)

```
journalctl -u try.service -e
```

Для работы в окружении пользователя:

```
loginctl enable-linger
```

В `~/.config/systemd/user/try.service` пишем

```
[Unit]
Description=Try User Server

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/try/try.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/try/


[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Старт

```
systemctl start --user try.service
```

Автостарт

```
systemctl enable --user try.service
```

## screen

Для интерактивных скриптов, которые требуют вмешательства пользователя лучше воспользоваться screen

Запуск

```
screen -d -m -A -S try_screen /opt/try/try.py
```

Подключиться - посмотреть, ответить на вопросы

```
screen -r try_screen
```

Comment: Отлично, а если нет возможности писать в */etc*? Может будем учить пользователей создавать *пользовательские* сервис-файлы?

Comment: можно, но там нужна сессия пользователя, которую опять же надо прописать в /etc/

Comment: Какой */etc*? `systemd` пишет данные в каталог пользователя (или во временные каталоги, доступные пользователю в */run* и т.д.). https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User

Comment: Как вы стартанете сервис системд для юзера, кроме как `systemctl enable user@0andriy.service` ?

Comment: @eri `systemctl enable --user myservice.service` (без sudo)

Comment: @andreymal - 3 ньюанса. сервис выполнится только когда залогинится пользователь, закроется когда он разлогинится и стартанет несколько раз если пользователь залогинился несколько раз.

Comment: @eri `loginctl enable-linger` фиксит все три нюанса

Comment: но опять же правит `/etc/` =)

Comment: Но правит он его через DBus API, и это не требует прав root

Comment: лишь бы умолчания в logind.conf не помешали.

Comment: вроде пашет. попробую на новом проекте...) я вот на со сижу чтоб учиться